# After turning string to array some characters become this �

Tags: php, utf-8

Letters like čęąįęėįųų etc. become �. How can I prevent this or make so the characters would be same like before.

```
$x = 0; $b = 0;
$char2 = ''; //define a variable to collect all the chars
while ($x++ < 10) {
    $char2 .= $text[$b++]; //add to the char
    $char2 .= ' ';
}
```

Output example
Before: Aš ėjau.
After: A� �jau.

Comment: What is `$text`? An array of strings, or a string that you're accessing individual characters thereof?

Comment: I forgot one line, it's before the whole code; item = str_word_count($item, 1);

Comment: $text is a variable with a simple text, with chars like ęėęč

Comment: accessing a string via array notation is not UTF aware. You're pulling out individual bytes, and breaking the multibyte UTF-8 characters. You need to use the mb_substr functions to prevent this.

Comment: Thank you guys for help but none of the codes are working..

Answer (score 2):

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$x = 0; $b = 0;
$char2 = ''; //define a variable to collect all the chars
while ($x++ < 10) {
    $char2 .= mb_substr($text, $b++, 1); //add to the char
    $char2 .= ' ';
}
```

is what you want.

UTF8 chars are multi byte, so your 'š' consists of 2 bytes, but indexing with [] takes only one of them, and putting space between one utf8 char's bytes destroys it.

EDIT: you need specify internal encoding first.

Comment: mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    $x = 0; $b = 0;
    $char = ''; //define a variable to collect all the chars
    while ($x++ < $params->get('wordsinline1')) {
    $char .= mb_substr($item->zodziai, $b++, 1); //add to the char
    $char .= ' ';
}
I tried your code, but it's not working, or maybe I'm doing something wrong..?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your script file in write encoding..
I guess it should be utf-8 without BOM

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking into account that some of the characters take more than 1 byte, so when you take 1 byte out of a character that is 2 bytes wide, it will become something else. In this case `"�"`.

Here is a way to do what you want:

```
<?php
$text = "Aš ejau";
$chars = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $text ); 
$char2 = '';

foreach( $chars as $char ) {
    $char2 .= $char;
    $char2 .= ' ';
}


echo $char2;

//A š   e j a u
```